# Oracle APEX Text Page Item as non-editable hyperlink field from a SQL Query

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

My colleagues and I have spent too many hours trying to do what we think should be fairly simple to do but have had no success.  We have a table that includes a column of web addresses.  On our form page we are creating items in a grid where certain items needs to be non-editable actionable hyperlink fields for the users to click and have the link open in another page (i.e. Target = Blank).  We have tried these solutions from this blog with no success:

https://community.oracle.com/thread/618722?tstart=0

Here are our requirements specifically:

1. We have a text item:  :P2_link1 that pulls the web address in via SQL query in the 'Source>Source Used = Only when current value of item is null and Source type = SQL Query such as :

   select ref_link from table1 where step = 1.1;
2. On our Form Page, the item needs to te a non-editable item (i.e. they cannot edit the web address that is pulled in via the SQL query).  But the link needs to be actionable such that a new tab or window opens to the page referenced in the SQL query.

We really appreciate any help you can provide,

Thanks,

Comment: what type of report form are you using?interactive?classic?or tabular..I assume its tabular since user can edit the column. I suggest you change your report type to interactive or classic report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a Display Only item not a text item.

You need to construct the HTML for the link in the item source for example:

```
select '<a href="' || ref_link || '">' || ref_link || '</a>' 
from table1 
where step = 1.1;
```

By default this will display escaped like this:

```
<a href="http://bbc.co.uk">http://bbc.co.uk</a>
```

Edit the item, go to Security and set Escape special characters to No.

Now you should see a working link.

Comment: Hi, thanks fro your reply.  I have followed your instructions to a 'T' and <a href="http://bbc.co.uk">http://bbc.co.uk</a> still shows.  It is as if APEX is ignoring the Special Characters = No.  Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: I don't know - perhaps you could set your example up on apex.oracle.com and I can have a look?

Comment: Hi, I will try to do that later this week.  Interesting though, I looged out this past weekend and come back and now I am getting this error.  Error.  I did not change anything. "Computing item source value for page item P2_1_1_LINK.

ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small"

Comment: I'm away on holiday this week, but will look out on my return - or someone else may be able to help.

Comment: Hi, thanks.  Here is a test app for anyone who wants to give it a go.  I am using the new Oracle here whereas my version is 4.2 so I am hoping there is not going to be a big difference in terms of themes.  https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=43249:1

Comment: And...it works in APEX 5.0.  So this is likely to be a theme issue...wonderful :)  Tony thanks for pointing me down the correct path.  Hope you have a great vacation.  Your answer is marked as correct :)  If I find out what the theme issue is I will post for others, in case they have the same issue.